# RxJava: Understanding concurrent execution

Tags: multithreading, rx-java

In my example below (Kotlin, but fundamentals are same)

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {   
    val executor = Schedulers.from(Executors.newCachedThreadPool())

    Observable
        .fromIterable(1 until 1000)
        .observeOn(executor)
        .map {
            //1st block
            Thread.sleep((Math.random() * 100).toLong())
            Thread.currentThread().name + "-" + it
        }
        .map {
            //2nd block
            Thread.sleep((Math.random() * 100).toLong())
            it + "-" + UUID.randomUUID()
        }
        .subscribe(
            {
                println(it)
            },
            {
                it.printStackTrace()
            },
            {
                executor.shutdown()
            }
        )
}
```

I have noticed following:-

1. Execution always happens on same thread.
2. The items are always printed in order.

My questions are:-

1. Is it compulsory in reactive pattern to synchronize the execution of the stream? What if my elements are indepedent of each others and can be processed parallely.
2. Isn't there any way 1st and 2nd block can execute different items concurrently.

Basically since Rx chain wants to synchronize item processing, looks like it is using same thread to process all the items. This kind of defeats the purpose of multithreading if you application rely on Rx. Rx is said to be agnostic of the underlying concurrency implementation. Is it possible that I am using it wrong way?

Comment: Suggested reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#simple-background-computation

Comment: ok, I am on it.

Comment: Hey David, I did read the wiki manytimes over. I am sure subscribeOn won't help here as my obersvable create is non blocking. I guess the solution is to use flowable with parallel.

Comment: RxJava is synchronous by default, which means multiple subsequent `map`s will run on the same thread and they won't process different elements in parallel. You have to introduce concurrency via `observeOn` to have each stage run on a different thread.

Comment: Thanks @akarnokd as always :)